# Elegant way of processing an "options" parameter

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, constructor

In this constructor function I'm assigning everything to the proper variables. For the third parameter it accepts an `options` argument that contains the optional settings.

To prevent a `Cannot read property x of undefined.` error I'm always checking this variable by steps, since the `options` variable can contain *both* complex objects and primitive data types.

I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way I could write this?

**Constructor**

```
function LiveDate(timeUrl, element, options) {
    this.timeUrl = timeUrl;
    this.element = element;

    this.format = options && options.format ? options.format : LiveDate.formats.ISO8601;
    this.offset = options && options.offset ? options.offset : 0;

    this.weekdayNames = {
        long: options && options.weekdayNames &&  options.weekdayNames.long ? options.weekdayNames.long : [
            'Sunday',
            'Monday',
            'Tuesday',
            'Wednesday',
            'Thursday',
            'Friday',
            'Saturday'
        ],
        short: options && options.weekdayNames && options.weekdayNames.short ? options.weekdayNames.short : [
            'Sun',
            'Mon',
            'Tue',
            'Wed',
            'Thu',
            'Fri',
            'Sat'
        ]
    };

    this.monthNames = {
        long: options && options.monthNames && options.monthNames.long ? options.monthNames.long : [
            'January',
            'February',
            'March',
            'April',
            'May',
            'June',
            'July',
            'August',
            'September',
            'October',
            'November',
            'December'
        ],
        short: options && options.monthNames && options.monthNames.short ? options.monthNames.short : [
            'Jan',
            'Feb',
            'Mar',
            'Apr',
            'May',
            'Jun',
            'Jul',
            'Aug',
            'Sep',
            'Oct',
            'Nov',
            'Dec'
        ]
    };

    this.start();
}
```

Comment: Technically, this shouldn't even work because `short` and `long` are reserved words. I.e. the parser must fail to parse this code (but many JavaScript parsers probably try to adjust for the mild errors in the input...)

Comment: @wvxvw Haven't experienced any problems with it in Chrome, FF nor IE.

Comment: Section 7.5.3 of ECMA-262 standard lists all future reserved keywords. It may be OK to use this now, but the standard explicitly tells not to do it because in the future they may be given semantics incompatible with your code.

Comment: @wvxvw So technically it works, but it's just not recommended for the reason you just gave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this to clean things up a little:

```
options = options || {};

// Set to Default values first
this.weekdayNames = {
  "long": [...],
  "short": [...]
};

// Then check to see if we need to override
if ( options.weekdayNames ){
  for ( var key in options.weekdayNames ){
    this.weekdayNames[ key ] = options.weekdayNames[ key ];
  }
}
```

Furthermore, something like lodash's defaults function https://lodash.com/docs#defaults may be of use.